# Input string was not in a correct format. Convert.ToInt32(variable)

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public double CalculateBill(string quantity, string cost)
{
    double totalBill;

    this.Quantity += Convert.ToInt32(quantity);
    totalBill = Convert.ToInt32(cost) + Quantity;
    return totalBill;
}
```

I get no error with `this.Quantity += Convert.ToInt32(quantity)`
but I get

> Input string was not in a correct format.

with `totalBill = Convert.ToInt32(cost) + Quantity`

Comment: What is the value of quantity variable ?

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 requires that its input is a string variable convertible to an integer. If cost contains a comma, that's not an int but a decimal. In any case, when you are unsure about the inputs use the TryParse family of methods

Comment: the value is 2, passed through a session.

Comment: I used Convert.ToDouble(cost) and it worked, thank you Steve.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead, that will be much safer in case an empty string is passed, otherwise you will get same exception. The TryParse will return a boolean to tell whether the conversion succeeded or not, based on you can proceed with the calculation.