# System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format with OdbcDataReader.GetFieldValue

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, odbc, formatexception

I have a query like below

```
SELECT NAME, MARKS, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM STUDENTS GROUP BY NAME, MARKS
```

While iterating through the OdbcDataReader I am encountering System.FormatException the code and stacktrace were as follows:

```
Using dataReader As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader = CType(cmdODBCCommand.ExecuteReader(), System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader)
    While (dataReader.Read())
        Dim stuName As String = dataReader.GetFieldValue(Of String)(0)
        Dim stuMarks As String = dataReader.GetFieldValue(Of String)(1)
        Dim stuCount As Int32 = dataReader.GetFieldValue(Of Int32)(2)<-- Exception here
        ' The entire database contains only 10 rows still getting the format exception.
        ' Also tried like below
        'Dim x = dataReader.Item("Name")
        'Dim y = dataReader.Item("Marks")
        'Dim z = dataReader.Item("TOTAL") <-- Exception here
        'Dim stuCount As Int64 = dataReader.GetFieldValue(Of Int64)(2)<-- Exception here
    End While
End Using
```

Strack Trace:

```
System.FormatException was caught
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetInt64(Int32 i)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i, TypeMap typemap)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
       at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
  InnerException:
```

Are anyone aware of this issue and how to get rid of this?

I've tried all the solutions mentioned at following URLs:

[Input string was not in a correct format. Convert.ToInt32(variable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584907/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-convert-toint32variable)

[Not able to cast string to int. Error msg: Input string was not in a correct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339599/not-able-to-cast-string-to-int-error-msg-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-for)

[Input string was not in a correct format?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f66ce3fb-9761-4da8-8495-6866e5865402/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Comment: Do you have Option Strict Off? Normally you should get an `InvalidCastException` instead of a `FormatException`. Also, i doubt that you get the same exception at `dataReader.Item("TOTAL")` because there is no cast involved which could fail.

Comment: Why you added `c#` as well?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've Option Strict On
Option Explicit On. SonerGönül, I accept c# answers as well. But I prefer vb.net

Comment: What database engine are you querying against (Oracle, Access, Sql Server, etc ) ?

Comment: Try `dataReader.GetFieldValue(Of Int64)(3)` or look in the debugger for the type of `dataReader("TOTAL")`(which should not fail, otherwise you're not showing the real query/code).

Comment: @user957902 its against custom search server by OpenText™ Search Server

Comment: @TimSchmelter dataReader("TOTAL") or dataReader.Item("TOTAL") doesn't evaluate at all. Also updated the code I've tried int64, long and object types as well

Comment: I´m not a VB pro but isn´t the `GetFieldValue` index zero based? So you´d select GetFieldValue(0) to (2)

Comment: @AlexB. its a typo. Still Dim z = dataReader.Item("TOTAL") <-- Exception here

Comment: @viento: "it's a typo" sounds as if you don't show the real code which causes the issue. You've also mentioned that `dataReader.Item("TOTAL")` cause also the exception.  Now you state that it doesn't evaluate at all. What is correct? What does "doesn't evaluate at all" mean?

Comment: What does `Dim z as String = dataReader.Item("TOTAL").ToString()` return?

Comment: @TimSchmelter What I mean by doesn't evaluate is where the code is throwing exception. Its not modified code. I've set up a sample console app and from where I've extracted the code out., Alex B  dataReader.Item("TOTAL") itself throws the exception

Comment: Based on what you're saying, I'd try calling `dataReader.FieldCount` to make sure you have 3 fields as it seems like you aren't getting 3. Does your query return what you expect if you run it directly against your database? Does `dataReader.GetFieldType(2)` also throw an exception? I'm guessing OpenText™ Search Server might not support Count...?

Comment: From the exception stack track we can conclude 1) A column index of 2 does exist 2) Its raw ODBC data type appears to be a a String type 3) whatever string data is returned is not of a format that it can be parsed into an integer. Try returning column index 2 as a string as @AlexB. has suggested. I think that will shed a lot of light on what is going on.

Comment: @user957902 I tried Alex B's suggestion too. It is throwing same error.. Stacktrace is exactly the same as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Is there a command prompt for open text that you can execute the query and see what happens ? I'm wondering if there is extra text in the output stream. SQL Server has the "set nocount off" that keeps info messages out of the output stream that can cause problems with result sets. I am wondering if there is something similar for OpenText ? What does your ODBC connection string look like for the connection ?

Comment: After a lot of experiments and trials 'dataReader.GetOrdinal("TOTAL")' resolved the issue

Comment: GetOrdinal returns the column index of the column name supplied. It does not return the actual value of the column.

Comment: Oh.. that's why I'm always getting the same value of 2..